# Setting an Interval between draws on a Canvas (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

Basically I'm trying to draw a sequence of lines on a Canvas object with a short pause in between each line being drawn. Unfortunately as I have it now it does pause but I don't see any of the intermediate steps, which is to say I see it before and after it's drawn but nothing in between. I've tried System.Timers.Timer but it gave me an error that said the canvas was owned by another thread. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried putting your drawing sequence in a storyboard? you can stop/start them pretty much at will, or just time them to what you want.

Comment: I had no idea about storyboards. This looks like it's going to work. Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 1):

In WPF, I would recommend using System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Controls in winforms do not play nice with threads.  There is a timer class specifically made for working with winform controls.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx

It can be found in your toolbox in VS

Comment: I tried to add `using System.Windows.Forms;` to my file but it said that Forms isn't a part of System.Windows. What's going on?

Comment: you would need to add a reference to the System.Windows.Forms assembly for it to find the classes. Don't do this though, as Muad stated, you are using WPF which uses a different set of assemblies altogether compared with WinForms, best not to cross over (unless you have a good reason)